"Html" Component turning black after setting occlude to "blending"
pretty new to r3f but having a blast so far. I've run into a bit of an issue when rendering HTML into the scene with the drei helper. I'll drop the code from my render function below:
<group ref={group}>
            <LogoMesh ref={logo} />
            <mesh
                position={[-0.7, 0.5, -0.15]}
                scale={1.4}
            >
                <boxGeometry args={[0.5,0.11,0]} />
                <meshBasicMaterial transparent map={subTexture} />
            </mesh>
            <mesh
                ref={boxRef}
                position-y={0.5}
                position-z={-0.8}
                scale={0.8}
                visible={visible}
            >
                <boxGeometry args={[4,2,0]}/>
                <meshBasicMaterial transparent map={bgTexture}/>
            </mesh>
            <mesh>
                <Html
                    occlude="blending"
                    receiveShadow // Make HTML receive shadows
                    transform
                    distanceFactor={1}
                >
                    <CyberButton>ENTER</CyberButton>
                </Html>
            </mesh>
        </group>

on my <Html/> component you can see I've set occlude="blending" as this seems like standard practice now to get realistic depth within the 3D scene, but whenever I set occlude to blending it renders as a black box like this:
occlude set to blending
instead of how it does when occlude is just set to true, but doesn't properly occlude with the depth of the scene:
occlude set to true or raycaster
I feel like I'm probably missing something very simple, like a prop dealing with receiving light or something, but can't find anything yet, has anyone come across this before?

I had the same issue, and after digging around, I found that the black box problem happens because the occlude="blending" setting is trying to blend the HTML element with the scene’s depth buffer, but it conflicts with certain materials or lighting settings.
There is few things to try that helped me fix it:
Check the zIndexRange Prop:
<Html
  occlude="blending"
  receiveShadow
  transform
  distanceFactor={1}
  zIndexRange={[1, 0]} // Add this to manage depth blending
>
  <CyberButton>ENTER</CyberButton>
</Html>

Verify Material Transparency
<meshBasicMaterial
  map={subTexture}
  transparent
  opacity={1} // Make sure opacity is set to 1 (or a value that works)
/>

Update Your Packages: Ensure you're using the latest versions of @react-three/drei and @react-three/fiber
Use occlude="true" (Alternative Test): If occlude="blending" is still problematic
<meshBasicMaterial
  map={bgTexture}
  transparent
  depthWrite={false}
/>


So I was able to get this to work, but only if I removed my custom shader pass, having it included in the EffectComposer causes it to turn black again. Strange thing is I tried to recreate it here and it works fine with my custom shader pass. the actual project is a bit more complicated than that due to some cms stuff and using next over react, but for the most part this logic is the same so I'm a bit stumped.

Also, it seems the z-index fix only works if html is registering as a lower z-index to canvas (makes sense) but this also prevents any mouse over events  Maybe setting the raycaster explicitly could be a work around?
